# How to get the global path where lua is installed

Tags: lua

I'm writing a lua application that will contain a relative path, where no matter where lua is installed it will copy a file to clibs folder for example

```
getPath = getWhereLuaInstalled (could be C:\program file(x86)\lua\5.1 or c:\lua\5.1..)
```

Using the package.path will return for me all the path lua will search to find the executable.
Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: Why isn't `package.cpath` what you want? Yes, it will contain multiple paths but they should all work.

Comment: @EtanReisner Hi, well I only need a single path to copy a file to lua/5.1/clibs and use this as default path, this why I don't need all of them

Comment: Parse out, say, the first path from `package.cpath`. Also, Lua is frequently embedded within another program, and thus not really "installed" on its own.

Comment: Right, if you need a single path and get a list of them just pick one. But unless this is an installer application I would suggest not doing this at all. If it is an installer then using the installer stored location (in the registry maybe) is probably a better idea if you can find it.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Here what I need to do, I have a dll that it path will be added to the registry, the lua application will store the dll in lua/5.1/clibs, depending on the user where lua is embedded to use the complete path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are designing this for a windows machine (.dll and your example paths indicate this) so this is a possible solution.

```lua
local io = require "io" 

function getWhereLuaInstalled() 
  local handle = io.popen('where lua')
  local path = handle:read('*a'):match("(.*\\)")
  handle:close()
  return path
end
```

This can easily be modified for linux systems by replacing `where lua` with `which lua`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you just use a dot for that (`"."`). You can add relative paths to it: `./my/relative/path`